# Coding theory number theory book

Tags: book-recommendation

Can somebody help me with some suggestions for books on number theory,for beginners level.
Is there any book on number theory and coding theory or cryptography combined?

Answer (score 0):

You could try: A Course in Number Theory and Cryptography by Neal Koblitz, Springer GTM

Comment: Is it for beginners

Comment: Well it certainly is a nice text to begin with :)